# RubyOnRails в Docker

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails, docker

Пытаюсь запустить RoR в докере. Написал такой конфиг:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.3"

volumes:
  notused:

services:
  postgres:
    build: ./hms-db
    container_name: hms-database
    volumes:
      - ./hms-db/pgdata:/var/lib/pgsql/data
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=hms-api
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=

  api:
    build: ./hms-api
    command: rails server
    container_name: hms-api
    volumes:
      - ./hms-api:/usr/src/app
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
      - postgres:db
```

**./api/Dockerfile**

```
FROM ruby:2.4.2
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY Gemfile* ./
RUN bundle install
COPY . .
EXPOSE 3000
```

**./db/Dockerfile**

```
FROM postgres
EXPOSE 5432
```

**database.yml**

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  username: hms-api
  host: db
  password:
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 5 } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: hms-api_development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: hms-api_test
```

Получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: делал по https://docs.docker.com/compose/rails/ всё работает как надо

Answer (score 2):

В docker-compose.yml добавить:

```
networks:
  net:
```

Название проекта можно изменить в .env .

```
COMPOSE_PROJECT_NAME=project
```

Тогда host postgres будет postgres.project_net.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй в качестве хоста базы записать не db а postgres (название сервиса в docker-compose)

Comment: Вы не могли бы попробовать и более подробно описать решение?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том что я запускал контейнер и не билдил его заново

```
docker-compose up --build
```